# How can I view a short's bit representation?

Tags: c++, bit, short

If I have this as pointer to memory as a pointer to shorts:

```
unsigned short* ms = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(_memory);
```

and I know the size of ms (number of this shorts), I would like to see running through all these shorts and their binary representation.

How can I access the bits of each short in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cout << "\t" << dec << x << "\t\t Decimal" << endl;
cout << "\t" << oct << x << "\t\t Octal" << endl;
cout << "\t" << hex << x << "\t\t Hex" << endl;
cout << "\t" << bitset<MAX_BITS>(x) << endl;
```

try through bitset

EDIT(added code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  unsigned short _memory[] = {0x1000,0x0010,0x0001};
  unsigned short* ms = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(_memory);
  for(unsigned short* iter = ms; iter != ms + 3/*number_of_shorts*/; ++iter )
  {
    bitset<16> bits(*iter);
    cout << bits << endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i<16; i++)
    {
      cout << "Bit[" << i << "]=" << bits[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <iterator>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    unsigned short _memory[] = {0x1000,0x0010,0x0001};
    unsigned short* ms = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(_memory);
    unsigned int num_of_ushorts = 3;//

    std::copy(ms, ms+num_of_ushorts, ostream_iterator<bitset<16>>(cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: how can i convert my bitset<16> bits(*iter) into short ms[i]?

Answer (score 4):

To see the binary representation of *any* variable of type `T`, you can do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void print_raw(const T & x)
{
  const unsigned char * const p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&x);
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(T); ++i)
  {
    if (i != 0) std::putchar(' ');
    std::printf("%02X", p[i]);
  }
}
```

You can plug this into your list of shorts.

<sub>(You could even replace `printf` by two lookups of index `p[i] / 16` and `p[i] % 16` in a suitable alphabet:</sub>

```
static const char alphabet = "01234567890ABCDEF";
std::putchar(alphabet[p[i] / 16]);
std::putchar(alphabet[p[i] % 16]);
```

Or replace it by a genuine *binary* printer:

```
void print_byte(unsigned char b)
{
  for (std::size_t i = CHAR_BIT; i != 0; --i)
  {
    std::putchar(b & (1u << (i-1)) ? '1' : '0');
  }
}
```

You can chain that into the previous loop instead of the two `printf` calls.)

Comment: +1, but tiny nit: `i` should be type `std::size_t`, not `unsigned`.

Comment: i have a error on putc: Error 1 error C2660: 'putc' : function does not take 1 arguments

Comment: 1) I wish I could see bits of the representation in a short
eg: 0001000100101011
this code does not do this.
2) how can I do if I want to change one of these bits 1 to 0?

Comment: @Gg: Easy: 0001 = 1, 0010 = 2, ..., 1111 = F. `putc` should have been `putchar`, apologies. @ildjarn: What don't we do in the name of pedantry :-)

Comment: Binary printing code added! I would personally prefer a lookup table, I suppose, but at least this one doesn't make any assumptions on the number of bits in a byte.

Comment: Isn't `CHAR_BIT` a macro? Is `std::CHAR_BIT` sensical?

Comment: @ildjarn: I thought it was just a constant somewhere. I wanted to avoid having some pedant or another pester me, "mweh, this should be `std::`" :-) Did I get it wrong?

Comment: Haha, you can just never please _some_ people. :-P §18.3.3/2 says `CHAR_BIT` is indeed a macro.

Comment: @ildjarn: Grmph. Any chance `std::CHAR_BIT` still makes sense, though? If not I have to edit again...

Comment: Don't think so -- that would expand to e.g. `std::8`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (size_t i=0; i<N_SHORTS_IN_BUFFER; i++)
    // perform bitwise ops
```

where `N_SHORTS_IN_BUFFER` is the number of shorts in `memory`.

The number of bits in a `short` is `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(short)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working under the assumption that an `unsigned short` has 16 bits, then you can retrieve each of them with bitwise operations:

```
for( unsigned short* iter = ms; iter != ms + num_of_ushorts; ++iter )
{
    int bitN = ( *iter ) & ( 1 << N ); // get the N bit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `_memory` points to a list of shorts your `ms` pointer can be used as an array.

```
unsigned short* ms = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(_memory);

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SHORTS_IN_MEM; i++)
    cout << i << "th element\t" << ms[i] << endl;
```